# Select proxy from Listbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, proxy, listbox

I have a listbox and I'm trying to select a random proxy from it and use it with HttpWebRequest, the problems I get are usually Uri Scheme is invalid or Cannot parse hostname
Here's some code

```
If ListBoxProxy.Items.Count > 0 Then
    Dim itemnumber As New Random
    Dim proxy = ListBoxProxy.Items(itemnumber.Next(0, ListBoxProxy.Items.Count - 1))
    Dim proxyObject As New WebProxy("http://" & proxy.ToString, True)
    Request.Proxy = proxyObject
    proxy = Nothing
Else
```

Comment: You've got to provide some of the proxies for us to test.

Comment: Hi! You could try by using Dim proxyObject As New WebProxy(new Uri("http://" & proxy.ToString), True)